# how to fill textbox with data from database

Tags: vb.net

Please help to fix the error:

> Conversion from string 'ini_value' to type 'Integer' is not valid

when I check where the error comes from, it's when it has to put the data into the TextBox but in the database the column is declared as decimal.

```
If Conn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then Conn.Close()
Try
    Conn.Open()
    Dim rd As SqlDataReader
    cmd = New SqlCommand("Select * from INI Where ini_id= 5", Conn)

    rd = cmd.ExecuteReader

    While rd.Read
        TxtMarginSLAperc.Text = rd.GetDecimal("ini_value")
    End While
    Conn.Close()
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try
```

Comment: [SqlDataReader.GetDecimal(Int32)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getdecimal) is expecting an integer value, the column ordinal.

Comment: Maybe, use the [SqlDataReader.Item(string) Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.item) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GetDecimal() function is expecting an integer (the column ordinal), try the following instead:

```
TxtMarginSLAperc.Text = rd.GetDecimal(rd.GetOrdinal("ini_value")).ToString()
```

The GetOrdinal() function will retrieve the column ordinal described by the column name provided.

The ToString() at the end will return a string value based on the decimal retrieved from the database.